# Using regex to get substring

Tags: java, regex

With Java Regex, how can I manage to get a subtring for a String with pattern like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBO....{a very long string of characters and symbols}
```

Where I need to get `image/png` however, it could be `image/jpg` or `image/xxxx`

Comment: Please post a sample input, desired output and attempt.

Comment: I see your sample input and desired output. But what's your **attempt**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the simple regex:

```
image/\w+
```

---

```
String str = "data:image/png;base64,iVBO....";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("image/\\w+").matcher(str);

while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

```
image/png
```

If you want the contents of `\w+` (which I imagine might be the case), you can place it in a capturing group:

```
image/(\w+)
```

and call `m.group(1)`.